# Changing Toolbar text programmatically from fragment in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an Activity with Fragments as the main content. 
This Activity has a Toolbar with a TextView inside:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(my_activity)

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
}
```

Here is the Toolbar in that Activity's xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <fragment android:name="org.siku.siku.MyFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/my_fragment" />

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the toolbar.xml I am using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolBarText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I can change the text easily from that Activity, but its impossible for me to change the text from the fragment:

I have tried accessing the TextView from the Fragment, but I am getting an error

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_frament, container, false)
    val toolbar = activity!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    val toolbarTextView = toolbar.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.toolBarText1)

}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object
>   reference

The error comes from this line: 
    val toolbarTextView = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolBarText1)

Which means I am not retrieving that TextView properly, but from the examples I saw, this should be the right way to do so.

Comment: `R.id.toolbar` isn't used in your layout.

Comment: It's in the <include/> of the Activity

Comment: Also, I can access and change the text of the TextView from the Activity no problem. It's really from the Fragment level that I am getting an error

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. How are you attaching the fragment, and can you post your entire Activity XML?

Comment: I've just updated the content to include the full Activity xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait until the `Activity` was created:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    activity.actionBar.title = ""
}
```

Because you did `setSupportActionBar(...)` in your `Activity`, `getActionBar()` should then **not** be `null`.

Edit: 
If you want to use the custom title TextView, your `findViewById()` approach should also work. Important thing is to just wait until the `Activity` was created.

Comment: They're using a custom title View though. Will the `title` setter work?

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! I will accept your answer in 2 min

Comment: I guess it will!

Comment: My approach will use the toolbars internal title textview I guess. I edited my answer to apply to the custom title textview :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

Create a class `ToolbarController`:

```
class ToolbarController(val toolbar: View) {

    fun setTitle(title: String) {
        toolbar.toolBarText1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        toolbar.toolBarText1.text = title
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```
public var toolBarController: ToolbarController? = null
```

and override `onPostCreate`:

```
 override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
        toolBarController = ToolbarController(topBar)
 }
```

Now in fragment `onCreateView` create a call a method called `initToolbar` defined as:

```
private fun initToolbar() {
    (activity as YourActivity)?.toolBarController?.setTitle("My title")
}
```

You can modify the `ToolbarController` class and do any changes if you want